# Is it okay to use LiveData objects inside a service?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-service, android-livedata, android-lifecycle

I am using Companion object in service to expose my LiveData to a fragment. Is this okay to use or will it cause me problems like memory leaks?

In my service:

```
  companion object {
    val timeLeftInSeconds = MutableLiveData<Long>(0)}
```

In my fragment:

```
 LockoutService.timeLeftInSeconds.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {...})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's fine because companion object is kinda like static fields, but I highly recommend to use a repository instead because it will increase you code readability and makes it more robust. Something like

```
object AppRepository{
    val timeLeftInSeconds = MutableLiveData<Long>(0)}
}
```

And in fragment

```
AppRepository.timeLeftInSeconds.observe(viewLifecycleOwner
```

Comment: Thank you. I am new and I don't totally understand static fields that's why I was worried because google recommends bound service or localbroadcastmanager for communication between fragments and services.

Answer (score 2):

No it's totally alright because companion objects are like static properties in java and are not bound to the class you define them in.
Also you can put it in the same file, outside of your service

LockoutService.kt

```
val timeLeftInSeconds = MutableLiveData<Long>(0)}
class LockoutService {...}
```

And access it without mentioning the service name